# Android Studio: Try to change Background based on Shared Pref, but reset to default background when force close

Tags: android, background, restart

So, i try to change Background based on Shared Preference onCreate like this:

```
**strong text**
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);
        prefManager = new PrefManager(this);
        String imagename = prefManager.getBg();
        if (imagename=="1") {
            RelativeLayout settinglin = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.settinglin);
            settinglin.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lginbg);
        } else if(imagename=="2") {
            RelativeLayout settinglin = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.settinglin);
            settinglin.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lginbgload);
etc...
```

It work fine for this function but the problem is, when the application force close it always return the background picture to the default background (in layout)
for example:

```
android:background="@drawable/lginbg"
```

I check the value of my shared Preference is not reset when force close (so the problem isn't in shared preference)

Can someone help me please with this problem